# how could I change the type of column in redbeanphp?

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I am using the RedBeanPHP, I have a string of numbers, is it possible to store it like the string, not a double type? My example is next, and it doesn't work:

```
    $participant = R::dispense('participants'); 
    $participant->setMeta("participants.number","string");
    $participant->number = $number;
    R::store($participant);
```

Comment: using now number_format($participant->number, 0, '', '') as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedBean will automatically try to guess the right column type for the data you provide. However, it will never shrink a column, (for example from `TEXT` to `INTEGER`), only widen (for example from `INTEGER` to `TEXT`).

If it's important for you that the database column is `TEXT` during development, you could therefore insert a `string` and delete it again to "trick" RedBean into making the column type `TEXT`.

For example, put this code snippet into some type of initialization script:

```
$participant = R::dispense('participants'); 
$participant->number = 'not a number';
R::store($participant);
R::trash($participant);

// Column 'participants.number' is now of type TEXT
```

As I mentioned earlier, RedBean will never shrink the column to `INTEGER` even if you never insert anything else than number strings again.

On the other hand, if it's not critical to you during development, you could just freeze the database before deploying to production and manually change the column type to `TEXT` in your database manager.

Answer (score 2):

Redbean check attribute given value to set the right type for the column, I would recommend you to work with freeze option off every time, but, when you need to change something, you just turn it on. I mean, just turn freeze on when you really need to perform some change on you table, for ex:

```
// the false param will disable db changes
R::setup('dns', 'user', 'pass', false);changes (freeze option)

//...
//... let's imagine you have some code here
//...

R::freeze(false);

$participant = R::dispense('participants');
$participant->number = 'intert any string'; // need to set field to string type
R::store($participant);

R::freeze(true);

$participant->number = '99.99';
R::store($participant);
```

I know it is not the best thing ever, but you just have to turn it on when you need to change something on DB structure. Essentially, in production environment you should always turn it off